# answers.semanticweb.com is dead. Should we do something about it?

Tags: discussion

The Q/A site answers.semanticweb.com had existed forever, it had a huge amount of great questions and answers. Miscontent with the managing company was a factor in the creation of Open Data.

The site seems to be dead now, but all of its content is reusable, [if we find a dump](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/questions-and-answers-from-answers-semanticweb-com).

Should we do something about it?

- Send them flowers?
- Import the questions/answers (if technically possible)?
- Write an eulogy describing how it helped us learn SPARQL tricks?
- Write an autopsy report describing how sites that do not provide easy-to-use dumps are vowed to being challenged and die? (reminiscent of Wikitravel/Wikivoyage)?
- Something else?

Comment: I think this is the right place - is there any news about this? I am also very interested

Answer (score 6):

Dumping the site seems a good idea. Since I have used the site a lot of times, I miss many good answers from there. If there is any chance of importing them to some stackexchange-community, it would be brilliant.

I just wrote a script, that pulls the most important data out of the dumped pages from the waybackmachine. A 20MB json dump is the result. For sure there could be some improvements necessary. But maybe it is a good starting point...

https://github.com/bastiion/answers.semanticweb.com-dump.git

Comment: actually, this should be the answer to the question on the main site https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9659/1511

Answer (score 3):

This dump was recently deployed at https://answers.knowledgegraph.tech/. Unfortunately, only questions having a score higher than 5 were imported.

Answer (score 1):

we should certainly add questions here, and to other stack exchange sites where relevant.
i can write a scraper to suck it all down, and i'll put it on github for the time being.
would like to see some coordination here with mods if possible, maybe there are easier ways?

doing some prep work before scraping and found this gem: [archive.org tutorial for sucking their sites via wget](https://blog.archive.org/2012/04/26/downloading-in-bulk-using-wget/) which looks promising, however after my initial run, it is not working. hoping someone has some information about its status, because it seems ideal here.

Comment: I don't have a dump. I have trouble understanding your answer, would you mind summarizing what you think we should do?