# semantic web technology questions should go to a new stackexchange community

Tags: discussion, site-scope

To my mind most of the questions about semantic web topics and technologies are off-topic in *open data* stackexchange.

While *open data* covers topics like:

- freely available/ open data pools
- knowledge bases
- where can I find (historical, governmental, environmental,...) data?
- apis and data formats

Semantic Data cover aspects of:

- reasoning
- ontologies
- ontology modeling
- formats and semantic libraries, that deal with RDF, OWL, SWRL...
- triple store and graph databases
- SPARQL
- linked data

For reference look at the tags statistics on the now discontinued answers.semanticweb.com Q/A https://web.archive.org/web/20160320175811/http://answers.semanticweb.com/tags/

There has been an almost similar question [Are all Semantic Web technology questions on-topic?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/a/248/14487)

This discussion is also related to the [discussion about answers.semanticweb.com migration](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/358/14487).

I'm thinking of opening a new site proposal on Area51. There has been something like, that was named [Big Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40518/big-data). But this term was too unspecific and did not really address semantic and linked data topics.

I would like to here some opinions on that before I start discussing at area51.

Comment: Some time ago I [proposed a Semantic Web SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53218/semantic-web) on Area51. Unfortunately, it took too long (IIRC, there weren”t enough people interested 1 year after submitting the proposal), so it was automatically deleted.

Comment: this is really a disagreement in semantics, no pun intended. the open web supplies open data, built atop all of the semantic web's technology. linked open data is one in the same as the semantic web. i've had a billion arguments with scientists who swear they know the semantic web up and down and i'm wrong...but i'm not.

Comment: Just discovered this as we started "Web Data" on area 51. The name and much else is still open, as is the possibility of merging with Open Data if it makes sense. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120833/web-data